# Add the query to have condition to use datediff function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to use `datediff` function in EntityFramework Core when I query the database entity.

I have the following query.

```cs
var delegates = await (from tn in _context.TrainingNotification
                       join cd in _context.CourseDelegate on
                           new { did = tn.CourseDelegateId, nid = (int?)tn.NotificationTypeId } equals
                           new { did = cd.CourseDelegateId, nid = cd.NotificationTypeId }
                                     where !cd.Disabled 
                                        && statusToFilter.Contains(cd.StatusType.StatusTypeCode)
                                        && cd.NotificationTypeId == 1
                                        && System.Data.Linq.DateDiffDay(DateTime.UtcNow.Date, tn.Created.Date) == daysToBeReminded
                                     select new CourseDelegateUser
                                     {
                                         CourseDelegateId = cd.CourseDelegateId,
                                         UserGuid = cd.UserGuid,
                                         NotifiedUtc = tn.Created
                                     }).ToListAsync();
```

I would like to get only those records whose created date is 5 days older.
How to achieve this?

Comment: As an aside, why do you use this comparison? `new { did = tn.CourseDelegateId, nid = (int?)tn.NotificationTypeId } equals { did = cd.CourseDelegateId, nid = cd.NotificationTypeId }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you're using in the query is a Non-[Sargable Query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) which is a low performance query.

Whenever a query has to perform a function on a value in a row, that value cannot use an index.  However if you switch the function to the value you're comparing, then SQL can use an Index.

Instead of:

```
System.Data.Linq.DateDiffDay(DateTime.UtcNow.Date, tn.Created.Date) == daysToBeReminded
```

Use something like

```
var createdOn = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(daysToBeReminded);

&& tn.Created.Date == createdOn;
```

Comment: thank you. should this be AddDays(-daysToBeReminded)?